# jQuery input value backup and replace on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I have a table of inputs that are read only, and these are populated from a DB. A user is going to be able to double-click on a cell and activate it for editing. In order to send the new data to the DB the user must press a button. The user can also double-click another cell after activating one, and that is my problem. I want to be able to replace the original value of the cell if the focus was lost to something else other than the button.

[I have this fiddle that represents my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/PnSdC/18/)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="1" type="text" value="Data 1" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <td><input id="2" type="text" value="Data 2" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <td><input id="3" type="text" value="Data 3" readonly="readonly"/></td>
      <td><input id="4" type="text" value="Data 4" readonly="readonly"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button>Send</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                var element = null;
                $('input').dblclick(function(){ 
                    $(this).data("backup",$(this).val())                    
                    if(element == null){   
                        $(this).toggleClass("active");
                        $(this).blur(function(event){
                                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                                            if(!$('button').is(':focus')){ 
                                                $(this).val($(this).data("backup"));
                                                //alert("button has no focus");
                                            }  
                                        },100);  
                                    });                  
                        $(this).attr('readonly',!$(this).attr('readonly'));  
                        element = $(this);                           
                    }
                    else{                            
                        if(element.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id')){
                            $(this).toggleClass("active");
                            $(this).attr('readonly',!$(this).attr('readonly'));                                    
                            element = null;
                        } 
                        else{
                            element.toggleClass("active");
                            element.attr('readonly',!element.attr('readonly'));
                            $(this).toggleClass("active");
                            $(this).blur(function(event){
                                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                                            if(!$('button').is(':focus')){ 
                                                $(this).val($(this).data("backup"));
                                                //alert("button has no focus");
                                            }  
                                        },100);  
                                    });
                            $(this).attr('readonly',!$(this).attr('readonly'));
                            element = $(this); 

                        }                                                                                
                    }                        
                });
    $('button').click(function(){
        var value = $('tr').find('.active');
        var data = value.val();
        alert(data);
    });            
});
```

Comment: I've seen this question before, I think the reason people aren't answering is that the demo is far too complex to get through easily. Can you simplify your JSFiddle demo to just the basics of what you want to do instead of pasting your entire project in there and making us parse? Might help you get a better/faster answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: So only the last cell double-clicked on should be changeable? For example, if I click the first cell and change it, then click the second cell and change it, the the first cell should revert to the default value?

Comment: @j08691 yes... that's the behavior I want.

Comment: @Pete the fiddle is a small representation of the code. By no means is the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your doubleclick you could do this to reset the data:

```
$('input').each(function () {
   if ($(this).data("backup"))
       $(this).val($(this).data("backup"));
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/PnSdC/21/

Comment: Thanks!That works great. I'm a n00b on JQuery but let me see if I understand. This code traverses through and checks if backup was set and if so it replaces it?

Answer (score 0):

This will help, but you need add condition for `other than the button`.

```
$('input').focusout(function() {
    element.toggleClass("active");
    element.attr('readonly',!element.attr('readonly')); 
});
```